# printing words with double letters prints twice

Tags: python, debugging, duplicates

I am trying to print the words that have double letters but they print twice (although the correct words are printed). What am I doing wrong?

```
phrase = "Donald hat seine Mutter gegessen"

for word in phrase.split():
    for letter in word:
        if letter + letter in word:
            print(word)
```

Comment: Your algorithm repeats for every letter in the word. If the letter is in the word twice it will check this letter twice and so print it twice.

Answer (score 1):

`letter` iterates for every `word` in `phrase`, so "t" and "s" are presents twice, for that reason you get "Mutter" and "gegssen" twice.

My suggestion: Use list to hold your results and then eliminate duplicates:

```
phrase = "Donald hat seine Mutter gegessen"

#Start empty list
duplicate = []

for word in phrase.split():
    for letter in word:
        if letter + letter in word:
            duplicate.append(word) #Append the word

#Remove duplicates
duplicate = mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(duplicate))
print(duplicate)
```

Yield:

```
['Mutter', 'gegessen']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search only every second letter:

```
phrase = "Donald hat seine Mutter gegessen"

for word in phrase.split():
    for letter in word[::2]:
        if letter + letter in word:
            print(word)
```

or better add a break after the first double was found:

```
phrase = "Donald hat seine Mutter gessgessen"

for word in phrase.split():
    for letter in word:
        if letter + letter in word:
            print(word)
            break
```

Final soulution:

```
phrase = "test Aachen Mainschifffahrt Spaß test Aachen Mainschifffahrt Spaß"

sz_is_ss = True

s = set()
for word in phrase.split():
    for letter in word.lower()[::2]:
        if not word in s and (letter + letter in word.lower() or "ß" in word and sz_is_ss):
            s.add(word)
            print(word)
            break
```

Prints:

```
 Aachen
 Mainschifffahrt
 Spaß
```

Comment: While this seems clever and cuts the iterations in half, this is still an O(n^2) algorithm (because `if letter + letter in word` iterates over the letters in the word again) when it should be O(n).

Comment: And of course this won't work if you take german words like "Moselschifffahrt" (same letter three times).

Comment: @Matthias Can I count double also for Eszett?

Comment: Example „Donald hat immer eine große Scheiße in der Straße gemacht.“ I split to words and then using my function return not only immer but also every word that contains ß.

Comment: Also how do I double letter with mixed case, for example Aachen.

Comment: @Pop I showed case insensitive search in my answer 12 hours before you asked for it in the comment to this question.

Answer (score 0):

To have each letter only once you can use a set. You can create it with `set(word)`. Then if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the letters are repeated twice print that word.

```
for word in phrase.split():
    if any(letter + letter in word for letter in set(word)):
        print(word)
```

To make this case insensitive apply `lower`.

```
for word in phrase.split():
    if any(letter + letter in word.lower() for letter in set(word.lower())):
        print(word)
```